# What constraints are there on subclasses of an abstract class?

Tags: angular, oop, typescript, inheritance

Suppose we declare an abstract class in Typescript as follows:

```
export abstract class A {

//my concrete method    
function add(x, y) {
    return x + y;
}

//my abstract method
abstract divide();       
}
```

If we have a subclass B that extends A, what are the constraints on B? More specifically, we know that B inherits from A so we already have a concrete method with add(), and we know we have an abstract method method with divide(), but can we also add other concrete methods in B that are not inherited from A. Can I define pow() in B and not declare it as an abstract method in A. Something as follows:

```
export class B extends abstract class A {

//my concrete method
divide(){//implementation details go here};

//another concrete method?
pow(){
    //insert imp details;  
}
```

This question was motivated by the fact that I'm refactoring code on two screens on an Angular 2/4 app where the two ts components share a lot of the same code. I'd like to create an abstract class and push the common code into an abstract class and add some abstract methods. However, I have few methods in each screen that are wholly independent from one another so I'd like to know if it is okay/bad/good practice to refactor the code along these lines. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derived classes can override abstract or non-abstract methods from the base class.  They can also declare their own methods as well.  It's totally fine.